# Searching my website open an ads page instead of my website home page

Tags: wordpress

i have this problem win i try to open my website on google search using a incognito page

[image: Text]

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Looks like you website has been infected by some sort of malware. I would recomend that you install Wordfence and run a scan with that plugin to see if Wordfence can detect something.

Comment: thank you i will do that

Comment: how has it gone with this? :) any progress